# At what point should I dedicate a server for SMTP

Tags: windows, email, smtp, windows-server-2012

I currently have a 2GB RAM windows server 2012 which is has IIS and SMTP installed on there.
Now I seen alot of people leave SMTP out on the webserver and buy a server just dedicated to handle the emails (SMTP server).

Now at this time I wont be having alot of traffic going in and out so I dont think it is wise to make such actions yet, is this correct?

If yes, at what point is it best to split the two servers up and dedicate a server just for emailing or at least split it off with the main web server.

Regards

Comment: You should dedicate a server to something at around the point that *not* doing so represents a capacity issue or other business risk that can easily be mitigated by moving the 'problem' subsystem to its own server.

Comment: I think it's important to define specifically how much traffic we're talking about.  "a lot of traffic" is a bit subjective and can mean different numbers to different people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a high volume of email you shouldn't need a dedicated email server.

It is common to dedicate a domain name like `smtp.example.com` or `mail.example.com` to email.  This can co-exist on the same server as the web service using the `www.example.com` domain.  Use of dedicated domains in this manner is a sign of professionalism.

A few things you should consider:

- Your mail server needs a static IP address.  If you have a dynamic IP address, use your provider's (ISP's) relay server to send mail.
- Your mail server's PTR record should match the domain your mail server uses.
- You should have an A record for the domain your mail server uses.
- rDNS (reverse DNS) validation should succeed for the mail server's IP address. (It will if the previous two rules are implemented.)
- An SPF record allowing your mail domain to send email from its IP address should exist.
- An SPF record preventing your web domain to send email should exist.
- An SPF record allowing your mail server to send email for your domain should exist.